# How to generate code from AST typescript parser?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

After I read the [Using the Compiler API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) article, I could get the AST from string-code.

But when I try to generate the code (by escodegen) **from AST** (not transpile it) **to code** I got an error:

```
Unknown node type: undefined
```

Is there a way to generate the ast to the code?

```
import * as fs from "fs";
import escodegen from "escodegen";
import * as ts from "typescript";

const code = `
 function foo() { }
`;

const node = ts.createSourceFile("x.ts", code, ts.ScriptTarget.Latest);

console.log({ node });

const x = escodegen.generate(node);

console.log({ x });
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-moon-t6n6y?file=/src/index.ts)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it by `createPrinter` and pass `node` to `printNode`.

Here working example:

```
const code = `
 function foo() { }
`;

const node = ts.createSourceFile("x.ts", code, ts.ScriptTarget.Latest);
const printer = ts.createPrinter({ newLine: ts.NewLineKind.LineFeed });

const result = printer.printNode(ts.EmitHint.Unspecified, node, node);
console.log(result); // function foo() { }
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-fire-4nwo7?file=/src/index.ts)

Answer (score 7):

I think it might help you:

```js
import * as ts from "typescript";

const filename = "test.ts";
const code = `const test: number = 1 + 2;`;

const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(
    filename, code, ts.ScriptTarget.Latest
);

function printRecursiveFrom(
  node: ts.Node, indentLevel: number, sourceFile: ts.SourceFile
) {
  const indentation = "-".repeat(indentLevel);
  const syntaxKind = ts.SyntaxKind[node.kind];
  const nodeText = node.getText(sourceFile);
  console.log(`${indentation}${syntaxKind}: ${nodeText}`);

  node.forEachChild(child =>
      printRecursiveFrom(child, indentLevel + 1, sourceFile)
  );
}

printRecursiveFrom(sourceFile, 0, sourceFile);
```

OUTPUT:

```
SourceFile:  
-EndOfFileToken:  
SourceFile:  
-EndOfFileToken:  
SourceFile: const test: number = 1 + 2; 
-FirstStatement: const test: number = 1 + 2; 
--VariableDeclarationList: const test: number = 1 + 2 
---VariableDeclaration: test: number = 1 + 2 
----Identifier: test 
----NumberKeyword: number 
----BinaryExpression: 1 + 2 
-----FirstLiteralToken: 1 
-----PlusToken: + 
-----FirstLiteralToken: 2 
-EndOfFileToken:
```

**UPDATE**

```
import * as ts from "typescript";

const code = `const test: number = 1 + 2;`;
const transpiledCode = ts.transpileModule(code, {}).outputText;
console.log(transpiledCode); // var test = 1 + 2;
```

**Generate AST back to code**

Please take a look [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#creating-and-printing-a-typescript-ast)
I know, this is not full answer, but it might help other people to answer this question.

Unfortunately, I have no time do dig deeper(

P.S.   Code taken from [here](https://learning-notes.mistermicheels.com/javascript/typescript/compiler-api/#getting-sourcefile-for-code)

Comment: In fact, I need the string-code. in my case I expect `function foo() ....`. so is there a way to generate back from ast to string?

Comment: In your update, it transpile. I want to regenerate (not transpile I said it in the question please)

Comment: @JonSud sorry, just don't have enough time to go deeper